# Heroku asks me to subscribe to Eco to scale dynos. I'm already subscribed to Eco

Tags: node.js, heroku, heroku-nodejs

Pretty much the title. When trying to spin up an eco dyno for my app in the Resources section of the Dashboard, I get the following error:

> Item could not be updated:
> Subscribe to Eco to scale your dynos. Learn more at https://blog.heroku.com/new-low-cost-plans

I can see that I am subscribed to Eco in the Billing section, and can see 1000 hours remaining (0% used).

Is there a wait before I can spin up dynos after subscribing to the Eco subscription? Or does it only kick in on the 1st of the next month?

I tried using the CLI and the Dashboard to scale a dyno. On the CLI I tried `heroku ps:scale web=1` and on the Dashboard I tried the toggle under the Resources section. Both tell me to subscribe to Eco to scale dynos.

Comment: Having the same issue. Did you figure this out?

Comment: Yep! For some reason collaborators can choose to pay for the Eco Plan, but only app owners can enable the dyno. I had access to the repository so I just created my own Heroku app and enabled dynos.

Comment: @YajasMalhotra please add your comment as an answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For some reason collaborators can choose to pay for the Eco Plan, but only app owners can enable the dyno. I had access to the repository so I just created my own Heroku app and enabled dynos.

Answer (score -2):

As of November 28th, 2022, free Heroku Dynos, free Heroku Postgres, and free Heroku Data for Redis® plans are no longer available. See our FAQ for more info. Eligible students can apply for platform credits through our new Heroku for GitHub Students program.

Comment: That's not what I asked. I already subscribed to the Eco plan and am paying.